# Spark cassandra connector Java API, cannot find symbol CassandraRow

Tags: java, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying out the spark-cassandra-connector-japi example from here:

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/7_java_api.md

The maven build fails with the following error:

> SimpleApp.java:[24,9] cannot find symbol [ERROR] symbol:   class
>   CassandraRow [ERROR] location: class SimpleApp

My pom.xml is shown below

```
<project>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>simple-project</artifactId>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <name>Simple Project</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
  <version>1.0</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency> <!-- Spark dependency -->
      <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
      <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
      <version>1.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.0-M3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.datastax.cassandra</groupId>
        <artifactId>cassandra-driver-mapping</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

Where is the class CassandraRow defined? I have gone through the code in package com.datastax.spark.connector.japi.CassandraJavaUtil and it is not defined there. The example asks to only statically import  com.datastax.spark.connector.japi for the example to work.

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make it work doing `import com.datastax.spark.connector.CassandraRow;`

I'm using the same dependencies as you (regardless of the version)

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.datastax.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-cassandra-connector-java_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.0-M2</version>
</dependency>
```